# (Perl) Searching a file for text from another file

Tags: perl, file, search

I've spent a few hours on this portion of my code and still have no idea how to make it work, so any suggestions would be great!

---

I have 2 files, list1.txt and dictionary.txt. list1.txt looks like

```
rs1
rs2
rs4
rs5
```

while dictionary.txt looks like

```
rs1 1 A G
rs2 2 C T
rs3 3 A A
rs4 4 G G
```

The columns are separated by a space - there are four columns.
What I want to do is for each of the words in list1.txt, search dictionary.txt for the word, and if it exists, print out the entire row in dictionary.txt into a third file. If the word doesn't exist in dictionary.txt, just print out the word.

So, if I were to run the program below with the files listed above, my result should look like

```
rs1 1 A G
rs2 2 C T
rs4 4 G G
rs5
```

The aforementioned program:

```
open(LIST1, '<', 'test_chr1_22.txt') or die "Could not open chr1_22.txt: $!";

open(OUTPUT, '>', 'test_chr1_22_all_info.txt');

foreach my $line1 (<LIST1>)
{
        foreach my $line (@DICT)
        {
            if ($line =~ m/"$line1"/)
            {
                print OUTPUT"$line\n";
            }
        }
}
```

This is the code I have as of right now. I know it doesn't have my second condition, which is where if the word doesn't exist in dictionary, then just print the word. However, I can't even get the first part to work out, which is where if the word is in the dictionary, then print the row. What I get from this a blank text file. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: put use strict; at the top of your code. You don't seem to have read @DICT anywhere like you have read LIST1

Comment: I forgot to include that portion of my code in the post, so I do have it. Thanks for the reminder though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`m/"$line1"/` is wrong for numerous reasons:

- None of your strings against which you match contain `"`, so this will never match.
- You don't escape the contents of `$line1` to form a regular expression from arbitrary text.
- You only want to match if the text is found at the beginning of the string.
- You only want to match if the text is the entire field.

Anyway, once you use replace the extremely inefficient nested loops with a loop and a hash lookup, the need for regex match disappears.

```
my %dict;
while (<$DICT>) {
   my ($key) = split;
   $dict{$key} = $_;
}

while (<$INPUT>) {
   my ($key) = split;
   print $dict{$key} // $_;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I just started learning Perl for this project I'm working on, so I'm still trying to figure things out. However, I do still have a question. How do I make my script print words that occur in list1 but not in the dictionary? Right now, it looks the script will only print when the word in list1 appears in the dictionary. I could be wrong - I haven't tried out your code yet because I'm not on my computer right now.

Comment: It defaults to using the line from list1 if if the key isn't in the dictionary (`// $_`)